# Comó ingresar una palabra y que no se imprima en pantalla

Tags: array, c

estoy intentando hacer el juego de "el ahorcado", uno de los requisitos es que al ingresar la palabra a adivinar esta no salga y salgan "*".

He estado intentando con getch, pero parece no detectar los saltos de línea'\n'. En teoria, si pones "progrmacion", deben salir 11* y no la palabra, pero del mismo debo guardarla en un array para usarla más adelante en el juego.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAXLONG 15

void inicio();
void jugar();

void getText(char[]);

int main()
{
   inicio();
   printf("\n\n");
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
void inicio()
{
   int selec;
   printf("Bienvenido a %cEl ahorcado%c\n\nMen%c:\n1. Jugar\n2. Salir\n", 34, 34, 163);
   scanf("%d", &selec);
   if (selec == 1)
      jugar();
   else
   {
      system("cls");
      printf("%CGracias por jugar%c", 173, 33);
   }
}
void jugar()
{
   system("cls");
   char palabra[MAXLONG];
   printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
  getText(palabra);
   puts(palabra);
}

void getText(char palabra[])
{
   int pos;
   char caracter;
   fflush(stdin);
   for (pos = 0; pos < (MAXLONG - 1) && (caracter = getch()) != '\n'; pos++)
   {
      palabra[pos] = caracter;
      printf("*");
   }
   if (caracter == '\n')
   {
      palabra[pos] = caracter;
      pos++;
   }
   palabra[pos] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Si pudieras incluir el código completo, incluyento las librerías que usastes, te podríamos ayudar más rápido a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Codigo editado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que necesitas hacer uso del modo gráfico de C para que el código pueda funcionar. La lógica de programación está ien, no hay ningun error, excepto que no inicializastes el modo gráfico para que puedas usar tu funcion 'void getText(char palabra[])'.

Puedes declarar las variables para inicializar el modo gráfico como globales, y luego hacer uso de closegraph(); para salir del modo gráfico.

No es necesario tener la variable MAXLONG para establecerle un tamaño fijo a la palabra que el usuario está ingresando, si no que lo que puedes hacer es verificar si el caracter ingresado no ha sido enter (Enter en código ascci = 13). Es muy buena práctica lo que haces, que tengas todo tu código organizado en funciones, para eliminar redundancias y gestionar de una mejor manera los errores.

Te dejo el código. Si la respuesta te ha sido de ayuda, por favor márcala como la correcta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>

//#define MAXLONG 15 //Esto es completamente innecesario, el contador pos hace mucho mejor el trabajo.
int driver = EGA, modo = EGAHI; //Declaracion de las variables del modo gráfico. Estas variables están siendo declaradas de manera global.

void inicio();
void jugar();

void getText(char[]);

int main() {

    inicio();
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void inicio() {
    int selec;
    printf("Bienvenido a %cEl ahorcado%c\n\nMen%c:\n1. Jugar\n2. Salir\n", 34, 34, 163);
    scanf("%d", &selec);
    if (selec == 1)
        jugar();
    else {
        system("cls");
        printf("%CGracias por jugar%c", 173, 33);
    }
}
void jugar() {
    system("cls");
    char palabra[MAXLONG];
    printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");

    getText(palabra);

    printf("\n");
    puts(palabra);
}

void getText(char palabra[]) {
    int pos = 0;
    char caracter;
    fflush(stdin);
    initgraph (&driver, &modo, "C:\\tc20\\BGI"); //Llamado a inicializar el modo gráfico

    while ((caracter=getch()) != 13) {
        pos++;
        palabra[pos] = caracter;
        printf("*");

    }
    pos++;
    closegraph();
    palabra[pos] = '\0';
}
```

La palabra la tienes que ingresar en la ventana del modo gráfico.

[image: Pantalla del modo gráfico]

[image: Confirmación de la Palabra Ingresada]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ha funcionado